# Why doesn't the voicemail indicator show up when I have voicemail in CyanogenMod 7?

Tags: cyanogenmod, voicemail

I'm not sure if this is a question I should be asking my carrier or not, but hopefully someone might be able to point me in the right direction. I recently switched to CyanogenMod version 7, and the experience has been great, for the most part. I have voicemail service from my mobile provider, and under `Settings > Call Settings > Voicemail settings` I have my voicemail number set. However, if I let a call go to voicemail, my phone will indicate that I have missed a call, but not that the message has gone to voicemail.

**How can I get the voicemail indicator to appear in CyanogenMod 7**?

Thanks!

Comment: What device are you using? Are you using a "Visual Voice Mail" app? Are you using a nightly version of CyanogenMod?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it could be a known, or at least [reported](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=2801&q=voicemail&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Version%20Model%20Network%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Priority), issue, depending on the device you are using.

A few users report that on some carriers (looks like mostly in Canada) they have the exact issue with the Desire Z, running CyanogenMod.